# How do I get the list of stylesheets from CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, css, casperjs

How do I get the list of stylesheets from CasperJS?
I want what 'document.styleSheets' returns in Chrome.

eg:

```
StyleSheetList {0: CSSStyleSheet, 1: CSSStyleSheet, 2: CSSStyleSheet,3: CSSStyleSheet, 4: CSSStyleSheet, 5: CSSStyleSheet, 6: CSSStyleSheet, 7: CSSStyleSheet, 8: CSSStyleSheet, 9: CSSStyleSheet, 10: CSSStyleSheet, 11: CSSStyleSheet, 12: CSSStyleSheet, length: 13, item: function}
```

Comment: And what does `document.stylesheets` return from the page context?

Comment: @ArtjomB.thanks, I corrected the typo.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: 'document.styleSheets' returns [object StyleSheetList]. I don't know how to get the various attributes of the Stylesheets from it.

Comment: The same way you do in Chrome. Again, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You access the style sheet in the same way, you would access it in Chrome, but before you do it, you have to get it from the page context.

```
var css = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return document.styleSheets;
});
casper.echo(css[0].href); // href of first stylesheet
```

Comment: B, Thank you. This works, but few of the objects in the array are Null. When we hit them we see the following error - 
    TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'css[i].href')
If I see 10 styleSheets with href in Chrome Inspector, I get only one non-null styleSheet from this piece of code. Why is that?

Comment: Check that `css.length > i` before using it. Pages may be different when opened in PhantomJS compared to Chrome. If this doesn't solve it, retrieve the attributes of your choice directly in the page context.